# What's the difference between "woulda" and "would've"?

Tags: would

One of my students asked me today what the difference is between "woulda" and "would've" in spoken English.

I think it has to do with the sound that follows, right? If the sound in the next word is a vowel, we use "woulda," but if it's a consonant, we use "would've." Is this correct, or vice versa?

I feel like they can be interchangeable too, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Personally, I would never say "woulda" and would try to avoid "would of"

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `woulda` is just a lazy / incorrect version of `would've`. Similary to how `would of` is almost always an incorrect version of `would have`. My advice would be to try to say `would have`, to shorten it to `would've` if you must, and to avoid `would of` and `woulda` altogether.

Comment: Pronounce it yourself and listen to what you say. If you're not a native English speaker, find some and listen to them talk. Don't believe anything you read online about correct language.

Comment: "Woulda" is used in rapid and fluent speech, and I wouldn't call it "lazy" or "incorrect" in speech, although it wouldn't be written unless it was used as "eye dialect."

Comment: Quote for the day - (from 'Mass and Count Nouns' by @John Lawler) : _The language can get along without us_ .

Answer (score 3):

First, the question has the same answer with most other modal auxiliary verbs besides *would*, e.g:

- *would have, may have, might have, must have, should have, could have*
- *would've, may've, might've, must've, should've, could've*
- *woulda, maya, mighta, musta, shoulda, coulda*
- /wʊdə, meyə, maytə, məstə, ʃʊdə, kʊdə/

  > *Willa* is unusual, because *will have* is unusual; normally *will* prefers to contract with a subject (ideally a personal pronoun) rather than with a following *have*. And *shall*, the remaining modal auxiliary, never appears with a following *have* in American English, since it's restricted to two first person question constructions exemplified by *Shall I open the door?* and *Shall we dance?*

Phonologically, the auxiliary *have* in these compounds is never pronounced /hæv/ like the verb *halve*; since the modal is stressed, the *have* is unstressed, and therefore reduced to a central schwa vowel /ə/, like what happens to the *to* of *want to, got to, have to* resulting in *wanna, gotta, hafta* in eye spelling, or /wanə, gatə, hæftə/ in speech.

All that's left of *have,* in unstressed position, is /əv/, and that's why people spell these constructions *might of* and *should of*, etc. It's the best way English offers to represent what people say, and people take any opportunity to be clear when they can.

The question of whether the /v/ of /əv/ gets pronounced or not usually depends on (a) how fast the speaker is talking and (b) what sound comes after the /v/. But there are other factors as well, and one speaker will vary a lot from one instance to another, and speakers will vary from one another individually, so it's not a matter of just two representations. To say there are no hard-and-fast rules is to understate the case; it's moment-to-moment individual judgement all the way.

Generally, it's hard to say /v/ before another consonant; names like *Vbirski* or *Dromovd* look difficult to pronounce, whereas *Varski* and *Dromova* don't. But it's possible, and some people have convinced themselves that they always say *might've* with a real /v/, no matter what they actually do. Some even believe they're really pronouncing *have*, again no matter what.

This is all about the language. English spelling is just medieval technology, so it's no wonder eye dialects of all sorts spring up everywhere.

Comment: Now, I think that even further contracted forms such as "he'd a" work the same way, but it would be good to cover this in your answer, even briefly.

Comment: Once you get into the variations in contracting, there's no end in sight. Frankly, I thought this was way too short, but so is life.